# Maven: version appears to affect relativePath

Tags: maven, maven-3

I am getting two different results when the parent pom's version is different but the relative path is the same. From my limited understanding of the relativePath tag, is that the relativePath overpowers the version, but it appears as though version is taking precedence over relativePath. Does relativePath not work with version? What is the difference between the following:

```
<parent>com.company.thing</product>
    <groupId>a-pom-file</groupId>
    <version>a</version>
    <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>
```

and

```
<parent>com.company.thing</product>
    <groupId>a-pom-file</groupId>
    <version>b</version>
    <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>
```

Comment: Which version of the artifact do you have in the path `../pom.xml`. Take a deep look onto the output of maven, cause it could be that maven tries to resolve it against your local repository instead of the one you have in `..`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the relativePath does not overpower the version. The version must be correct and available. It must be available either in the repository, in the default location (the pom file being one directory up from the current project) or your specified relativePath. So in your scenario the relativePath really has no effect as that is where Maven will look for your parent pom by default.

http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Project_Inheritance

Comment: First off, let me mention that I am refactoring an incorrect usage (ant-like) of Maven to follow industry standard, hence the questions. Regardless, it appears as though if I have multiple levels of parents then my relativePath becomes corrupted along the way requiring the subsequent parent pom must have an empty relativePath tag, such as: <relativePath></relativePath>. Any thoughts on why?

Comment: Not really, we are using multiple levels of parents in some cases, but we also have relativePath explicitly set in all those cases.